# company value, shares, NPV

Tags: stock-market, value, firm

Let's say we want to evaluate the value of a company. One way is to calculate the present value of the cash flows. I do not specify the cash flows  and the discounting rates $r_i$ here. Then the present value of the company is

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty } \frac{\textrm{CF}_i}{(1+r_i)^i}$$

The sensitive part is the assumption of the infinite existence of the company. Are there any (empirical) criteria which allows us to estimate  the lifetime of a company?

The criteria might be the market share, the sector, location, etc. of the company.

Thanks for reading the question.